# How To set Text on Div Border?

Tags: html, css

I want to div css for make a div on which name of div is display on top right side border. Like:  -----------DEMO--------------------------------------

Comment: have you tried something, if you can share some code ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Here you can not ask for code directly. you have to tried and if any problem then ask here. we will help you then. I answer here, i think need something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need like following:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="test">
   <span>Your text </span>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.test {
border: 1px solid #000000;
line-height: 0;
text-align: left; 
margin-top:40px;
height:100px;
width:400px;
}

.test span { 
background-color: #ffffff;
padding: 0 10px;
margin: 0 20px;
}
```

Check [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NpP5F/117/)